# Activiti BPMN - How to pass username in variables/expression who have completed task?

Tags: variables, hive, workflow, activiti, bpmn

I am very new to Activiti BPMN. I am creating a flow diagram in activiti. I m looking for how username (who has completed the task) can be pass into shell task arguments. so that I can fetch and save in db that user who has completed that task.

Any Help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hi Ravi, can you specify which version of Activiti are you using?

Comment: currently i m using activiti 6.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used activiti:taskListener from activiti app you need to configure below properties
1. I changed properties in task listener.
2. I used java script variable for holding task.assignee value.

Code Snip:-

Answer (score 2):

Here's something I prepared for Java developers based on I think a blog post I saw

edit: https://community.alfresco.com/thread/224336-result-variable-in-javadelegate

---

RESULT VARIABLE

Option (1) – use expression language (EL) in the XML

```
<serviceTask id="serviceTask"
    activiti:expression="#{myService.toUpperCase(myVar)}"
    activiti:resultVariable="myVar" />
```

Java

```
public class MyService {
    public String toUpperCase(String val) {
        return val.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

The returned String is assigned to activiti:resultVariable

HACKING THE DATA MODEL DIRECTLY

Option (2) – use the execution environment

Java

```
public class MyService implements JavaDelegate {
    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
        String myVar = (String) execution.getVariable("myVar");
        execution.setVariable("myVar", myVar.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

By contrast here we are being passed an ‘execution’, and we are pulling values out of it and twiddling them and putting them back.

This is somewhat analogous to a Servlet taking values we are passed in the HTMLRequest and then based on them doing different things in the response.  (A stronger analogy would be a servlet Filter)

---

So in your particular instance (depnding on how you are invoking the shell script) using the Expression Language (EL) might be simplest and easiest.

Of course the value you want to pass has to be one that the process knows about (otherwise how can it pass a value it doesn't have a variable for?)

Hope that helps.  :D

Answer (score 1):

Usually in BPM engines you have a way to hook out listener to these kind of events. In Activiti if you are embedding it inside your service you can add an extra EventListener and then record the taskCompleted events which will contain the current logged in user. 
https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#eventDispatcher

Hope this helps.